# If we use Interceptor clone feature, will clone duplicate the request?

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I am using Ionic 5 and setting up interceptor for adding the token to the header. Unfortunately the request is being triggered twice , with the authentication token once and without token . In other words onw triggered via the interceptor and the other one before interceptor.

In the network I am seeing two request made, one without header modification and the other with the Authentication token by the interceptor. I would want only the intercepted request to make the request. Kindly help me sort this out.

**service file**

```
// http.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  apiUrl = 'https://localhost:8100/api/getdetails';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDetails(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('response received')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getDetails', []))
      );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  /** Log a HeroService message with the MessageService */
  private log(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

**interceptor.ts**

```
//httpConfig.interceptor.ts
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  loaderToShow: any;
  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController
    ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const token = "my-token-string-from-server";

    //Authentication by setting header with token value
    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': token
        }
      });
    }

    if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    }

    request = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
    });
    this.showLoader();
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('event--->>>', event);
        }
        return event;
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        return throwError(error);
      }));
  }
  showLoader() {
    this.loaderToShow = this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Processing Server Request'
    }).then((res) => {
      res.present();

      res.onDidDismiss().then((dis) => {
        console.log('Loading dismissed!');
      });
    });
    this.hideLoader();
  }

  hideLoader() {
      this.loadingController.dismiss();
  }


}
```

**modified header request made by Interceptor**
[image: modified header request made by Interceptor]

same request also made by httpclient before being modified by Http Client.

> I would  want a solution where only one request which is modified should be
> sent on click of a button.

Comment: could it be that one is an `OPTION` preflight request, and the other one a `POST`? Also if there is a token and no `content-type` the `Authorization` header gets overwritten by the `content-type` setting. You should do the same as you did with the `Accept` header, using `set` and not `setHeaders`

Comment: No, typically `clone` does not execute the request twice, because the request is only executed when you call `next.handle`. Maybe one of the requests is the OPTIONS request which typically is sent if you have a cross domain request?